# LSTM input in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, tokenize, keras, lstm

I am confused about the input vector in LSTM model, the data I am using is the text data, e.g. 1,000 sentences. I have two questions about the LSTM input layer:

1.If I would tokenize those sentences into the vectors (we can call it sentence vectors), is there a way in Keras to make sentence vectors given a document? Should be word level, right?

2.The second question is the 3D Tensor type in LSTM. I have 1,000 sentences (samples) and time_step would be 1 if I want to LSTM read one document at each time step, is that correct? The last one is the input dimension, this input dimension is the word dimension (100) in each sentence or how many word observed in each time step (10)?

Thus the LSTM tensor should be (1000, 1, 10) or (1000, 1, 100)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer to the first question. I have no experience working with Keras. However, I have some experience with working on Tensorflow.

For the second question, did you mean "I want to LSTM read one ***sentence*** at each time step". If your intention is to work with sentence sequence, I believe that is what you want to do as you are using LSTM, then you need to define the sequence length (number of sentences will be processed in one particular sequence). Sequence length can be defined by using time_step. So setting time_step = 1 would be incorrect. If you are working with sentence vectors then the last one is the vector dimension for sentence embedding.

For an example, if you have 1000 sentences in a document, each sentence is represented by a vector of size 100, and the sequence length is 5 (you want to process maximum 5 sentences in one sequence), then the tensor dimensions would be (None, 5,100). The first one is 'None' so that you can decide how many sequences you want to feed into the network later (minibatch learning).

Answer (score 0):

The input format is (nb_samples, time_steps, input_dim). In your case, the number of samples is number of sentences. Time steps is the number of words in sentence, so this would be the number of words in the sentence that has maximum words (other sentences have to be padded to match this length). input_dimension is the number of features used to represent each word. For example if you use word2vec embedding say with 100 or 200 dimentions (features), that would be your input_dimension.